# Clock configuration for ShiftRegister in ChiselUtil

Tags: chisel

ShiftRegister is a usefull function to synchronize external signal with the main clock with two flip-flop :

```
sync_signal := ShiftRegister(ext_signal, 2)
```

That work well in this case. But is there a way to use it with an other clock like this :

```
slowClk = Clock(reset=Driver.implicitReset)
sync_signal := ShiftRegister(ext_signal, 2, clock=slowClk)
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Chisel3 it's now possible using withClock(){}

We just have to surround ShiftRegister() call with withClock :

```
  withClock(clock) {
    led := ShiftRegister(blinkled, 4)
  }
```

See also multiple clocks domains chapter in [Chisel3 wiki](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/wiki/Multiple-Clock-Domains).

Answer (score 0):

If you look in ChiselUtil.scala, you can see that the ShiftRegister object has no clock input, so it can't include the functionality you suggest as written.

It would be easy enough to modify or extend the class (per Chapter 18 of the Chisel manual) to take a synchronizing clock as input.

Comment: Not so easy because object used under the ShiftRegister class doesn't take synchronizing clock as input.